# What Version of WebKit is included in Blackberry WebWorks?

Tags: blackberry, webkit, blackberry-webworks

All I can find is that is WebKit, which is useful because BBOS5 doesn't even have that!

But a specific version would be better.

(I'm trying to get PDF.js to work and would like to know if I should just give up. :/)

Comment: WebWorks does not include WebKit.  WebWorks is a framework that runs on top of the device and interacts with the browser.  There are actually 3 difference versions of WebWorks, for java-based BlackBerry smartphones, for BlackBerry PlayBook and for BlackBerry 10 devices.

Answer (score 3):

If you are really asking about the version of WebKit in the different BlackBerry devices, go check our repositories at http://github.com/blackberry.  There are 3 different repositories:

- [WebKit-BB10](https://github.com/blackberry/WebKit-BB10)
- [WebKit-PlayBook](https://github.com/blackberry/WebKit-PlayBook)
- [WebKit-Smartphone](https://github.com/blackberry/WebKit-Smartphone)

Answer (score 1):

WebKit was introduced to the web platform as part of the BlackBerry 6 OS. It has been there ever since (BlackBerry 7 Smartphones, BlackBerry PlayBook Tablet OS and now BlackBerry 10) and is used to power the native browser, and WebWorks applications (and even hybrid native apps that use an embedded web view).

The version of WebKit is included in the User-Agent HTTP header
http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/08/blackberry-10-user-agent-string/

Here is the current user agent of the BlackBerry 10 simulator:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; Touch) AppleWebKit/537.3+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.9.386 Mobile Safari/537.3+
```

Comment: Do all third party Blackberry browsers run in qnx Webview, in iOS fashion, or can they use their own port?

Comment: If you build your own browser using the BlackBerry NDK, it uses the native WebView - which provides the same WebKit rendering engine as the browser.  However, if you create your own WebView from scratch then you would also build your own rendering engine (tons of work, but technically possible) or port something that was built using C/C++

Answer (score 0):

The BB OS 5 Browser is not a WebKit browser.

Thanks

Naveen M

Comment: So WebWorks uses the system renderer, even though they explicitly say that it's WebKit?

(https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html)