# URL Error Message when opening an Input Date field on Blackberry using WebWorks and jQuery 1.8.2

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm programing an app for Blackberry using WebWorks 1.0.4.11, jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.

I've tested the app, but an error is appearing when I tap a date `<input>` field that is formed by the following HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">  
    <label for="fecha">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
    <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" value="" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" />
</div>
```

When I press the "date" `<input>`, the phone screen *briefly* shows the option to enter the date; but immediately after that, the URL error screen mentioned above appears.
I tested with a Blackberry Z10 (versions 10.1 and 10.2), and the URL error screen is not appearing with this versions.

The error message is:

> **Error. This webpage is unavailable. Check the URL and try again.**
>
> **The error is only on a Blackberry Z30 (version 10.2).**

The error is also present in other type of `<input>`s, like "select":

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="pais" class="select">Pais*</label>
    <select name="pais" id="pais" onchange="optionCheck()">
        <option value="Seleccione Uno" selected>Seleccione Uno</option>
        <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option></select></div>
         ...
    </select>
</div>
```

Any suggestions ??

Thanks!

Comment: Why the placeholder for a date input?

Comment: possibly browser issue? Can you install other browser on blackberry and test this also

Comment: Yes I think it's browser issue.
Should try to install some datepicker plugin written in js instead of the HTML5 date input type.

Comment: Where does the error "come", what is its exact formulation? Does the browser try to go to a new URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Version of WebKit is included in Blackberry WebWorks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345434/what-version-of-webkit-is-included-in-blackberry-webworks)

Answer (score 0):

[BlackBerry Webworks](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/), [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), and [Normal JQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) have all been updated since (especially webworks in this case), so I would recommend in any case to get the latest copies.

This does seem to be a browser issue, but it seems to be fixed in later releases of WebWorks (I took your code, put it in a fresh simulator, and it ran fine). Try upgrading and see if you can reproduce it.

If you can't upgrade, I would recommend just using the[JQuery Mobile DatePicker](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/datepicker/) or another one that you prefer